# Burn the identify-this-track tag?

Tags: discussion

Since "identify-this-track" questions are deemed off-topic, does anyone have any objections to me burning the "identify-this-track" tag?

Comment: It's a good idea to get rid of it if it is off-topic. With how common those questions are (and will be), maybe it's a good idea to also add it as a close reason.

Comment: Close the questions along the way.

Comment: I just re-tagged for now.  If more close votes come in, we'll clean those up.

Comment: @JCPedroza that off-topic reason has now been added and has replaced the generic off-topic reason.

Comment: http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic/37

Comment: I've voted to close this question as a duplicate of [Identification questions in general. What is allowed, and what is not?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/identification-questions-in-general-what-is-allowed-and-what-is-not) to help in organising the Meta discussions around the ID tags issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is is obsolete as the tag doesn't exist any more and the identification questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

*Just answering to remove this question from the unanswered list.*

---

The [identify-this-track](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-track) tag has been successfully burninated as of 2015-05-26 by @JohnnyBones as per [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/musicfans/query/418194/deleted-tags).

The current site policy (as of the date of this answer) on which ID questions are allowed can be seen here: [Identification questions in general. What is allowed, and what is not?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/3955)